# discord.js find date of last message from a user ID?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Ayo! I wanted to know if it's possible to get the last message date sent by a user and then show the date of said message on the console.

Example:

(user) last message was at (date)

Answer (score 0):

```
const userId = 1;
const { username, lastMessage } = await client.users.fetch(userId);
console.log(`${username} last message was at ${lastMessage.createdAt}`);
```